# How to make a Flexbox item the same width as other items but on a new line

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I want to set a Flexbox item the same width as the width of two Flexbox items combined. For example:

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.line-break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-2 {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="item-1">
  </div>
  <div class="item-2">
    <p>This is a text</P>
  </div>
  <div class="line-break" />
  <div class="item-3">
    <p>This is another text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

A side note: I'm using the React framework for my project.

How would I calculate the width for `item-3` so it would have the same width as `item-1` + gap + `item_2` dynamically?

https://codepen.io/InFusion-the-sans/pen/wvQRRxK

I've tried to set the `flex-basis` property on `item-3` to some percentage but the result is too far off the expected width I wanted.

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/knz73ygb/

Comment: Please do not edit the title to add "\[SOLVED\]" to it. Instead, pick an answer that helped you, or if none did, answer the question yourself, and mark that answer with the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra wrapper like so:

```css
.body {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem; /*this is the line break,   <div class="line-break" /> does nothing, since it doesn't have height*/
}

.top-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 2rem;
}
.item-1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-2 {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-3 {
  align-self: stretch;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="top-wrapper">
    <div class="item-1">
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <p>This is a text</P>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-3">
    <p>This is another text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a wrapper for the first 2 items so that those 2 items can create a combined width which can be followed by the 3rd item. And for a flexible width you need to add `width: fit-content` to the top-most container and then use `margin: 0 auto` for the horizontal alignment.

Note: I removed all the unnecessary codes.

```
.body {
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
    .body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 2rem;
        width: fit-content;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .first-2-items{
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        gap: 2rem;
    }

    .item-1 {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .item-2 {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .item-3 {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="first-2-items">
        <div class="item-1">
        </div>
        <div class="item-2">
            <p>This is a text. More text</P>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item-3">
        <p>This is another text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The way I understand the question, this is not the desired result for making the width of the bottom item equal to the width of the top two items combined.

Comment: @TimR You are right, I misunderstood. I have updated my answer.